# I am looking for a way to =filter and not overwrite data from previous cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a production order-bill of material master sheet. The issue I am having is when I use =filter to get my bom data I can only do one line item without a #ref error. I am hoping to find a way to =filter then add rows(push down the data) so data does not get overwritten.

This is working when I am only filtering for one line item
[image]

The issue comes when I drag the formula down to get the BOM info for ROW 2.
Error when dragging the formula through the sheet
[image]

I have highlighted the line item and filter results I am looking for. If anyone has a solution to add X amount of rows based on the filter results that would be great. I am currently at a loss. I have tried for weeks.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ubs9nthgk9h-DKxXMVhAjPZF8ot1F98nCcLccLbTbyE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have shared a link now.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ubs9nthgk9h-DKxXMVhAjPZF8ot1F98nCcLccLbTbyE/edit?usp=sharing
this is the one

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(BomMaster!$1:$17000, " ", "♦"), 
 BomMaster!A:A=B2&" "&C2&" "&D2),, 9^9), " ", CHAR(10)), "♦", " "))
```

[image]